# Type Script compiler showing error when compile in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular6

I have getting build error when Building Angular 6 and Asp.Net MVC application.
   I have also update Type Script typescript@3.2.4 but not solve my issue.

```
     Build:A 'const' initializer in an ambient context must be a string or numeric literal.
Error   TS1039  (TS) Initializers are not allowed in ambient contexts.  D:\newAngularApp\NewApp\NewApp\Client (tsconfig or jsconfig project)    D:\newAngularApp\NewApp\NewApp\Client\node_modules\@angular\common\http\src\response.d.ts   253 Active
Error   TS1039  (TS) Initializers are not allowed in ambient contexts.  D:\newAngularApp\NewApp\NewApp\Client (tsconfig or jsconfig project)    D:\newAngularApp\NewApp\NewApp\Client\node_modules\@angular\common\http\src\response.d.ts   259 Active
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I do not think angular 6 supports typescript 3.2.4. I am not sure if that is the cause of your error or not. I would include your `tsconfig.json` file in the question.

Comment: I have added tsconfig.json file in question.